# ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM - favicon not displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

I have the following two lines in the head section in my masterpage:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/Content/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

However, the favicon is not displayed in Internet Explorer (version 6, 7, 8). In Firefox and Safari the favicon works fine. I have even tried to replace href with the URL to my website (http://www......./Content/Images/favicon.ico) but that still does not work in Internet Explorer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not really mvc or asp.net related. You might consider changing the title/tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this post
http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/14/asp-net-mvc-2-throws-exception-for-favicon-ico.aspx

Comment: Yep, looks like adding routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico"); would solve the problem